# Makefile: install target usable from the CLI or a packaging system?

Tags: makefile, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

given this simple install target for my Makefile:

```
install: zrm $(CONF)
        install -D -m 0755 -o mysql -g mysql conf/lvm0.conf $(DESTDIR)/$(CONFDIR)/lvm0/mysql-zrm.conf
        install -D -m 0755 -o mysql -g mysql conf/inc1.conf $(DESTDIR)/$(CONFDIR)/inc1/mysql-zrm.conf
        install -D -m 0755 -o mysql -g mysql conf/dump0.conf $(DESTDIR)/$(CONFDIR)/dump0/mysql-zrm.conf

        install -d -m 0755 -o mysql -g mysql $(DESTDIR)/$(PLUGIN)
        install    -m 0755 -o mysql -g mysql post-backup-st-zrm.pl $(DESTDIR)/$(PLUGIN)

        install -d -m 0755 -o root -g root $(DESTDIR)/$(BINDIR)
        install    -m 4755 -o root -g root zrm $(DESTDIR)/$(BINDIR)
```

I can simply do `make install` as **root** (or use `sudo`) and it will beautifully install.
As foo (*unprivileged*) user, calling `make install` will returns an error (-o option needs super-user).

I need to change this so that I can both `sudo make install`, `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/foo` or even package this into .deb or .rpm and just call the install target from my Makefile.

What will be the best solution for me ? Replace install calls to cp ? Remove -o and put a chown/chmod ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make install command a variable that can be overridden on the `make` command line, something like

```
INSTALL_USER = mysql
INSTALL_GROUP = mysql
INSTALL = install -d -m 0755 -o $(INSTALL_USER) -g $(INSTALL_GROUP)
INSTALL_DIR = $(INSTALL) -d
```

I'd expect packaging systems to be able to cope with your makefile anyway, because it's the kind of things other people have written. Debian package building runs as root (or rather usually pretends to run as root, through [fakeroot](http://fakeroot.alioth.debian.org/)), so it will allow and see the ownership changes.

Note that [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) would [not allow the permissions you set](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-permissions-owners), since it requires all files to be owned by root unless there is a compelling reason not to. I can't see a reason for any of the files to be owned by `mysql` (or have I missed some mysql-specific reason why the plugins and configuration files can't be owned by root?). The reason is a security issue: if someone manages to overwrite files as `mysql`, they should not be able to inject code into executables and configuration files.

Since distribution maintainers may want to override the permissions you set anyway, don't agonize over this.

Comment: I know that on Debian, building a package can be faked as root. What I am not sure about, is how this is done with the RPMbuild system.

mysql:mysql is required in our environment and by mysql-zrm product as far as I know.